# Product prices not adding to cart in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

When adding a product to the cart eg. £99 the price displayed in the cart is £0.00.

I know that certain Woocommerce files in my theme are outdated and this particular issue has occurred since updating to Woocommerce version 3 and upwards.

I have tried updating cart.php and mini-cart.php in my theme files but the problem still persists. I have now reverted these files back to their previous versions.

I think there must be some outdated hook which means that the price is not pulling to the cart. I'm really struggling to find it. Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix the issue?